# Hoffman & Kunze Chapter 1 section 6 exercise 12

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is part 2 of the exercise 12 in section 1.6. Is my proof correct here?

Let $R$ be row-reduced echelon matrix obtained from $A_{m\times n}$. Show that $R=PAQ\quad (1)$, where $P$ is an invertible $m \times m$ matrix and $Q$ is and invertible $n \times n$ matrix.

*Proof*
Since $R$ is obtained from $A$, there is an elementary matrix $E$ which is invertible, such that
$$EA=R.$$
Hence we need to show that $$EA=PAQ.$$
Since $E$ is invertible:
$$A=E^{-1}PAQ,$$
but this is possible if and only if $E^{-1}P=I$ and $Q=I$, where $I$ is identity matrix.
Hence $E^{-1}=P^{-1}$. $\square$

*Edit*

Since $R$ is obtained from $A$, there is a matrix $E$ which is row equivalent to an elementary matrix, therefore it is invertible. And such that
$$EA=R.$$
Hence we need to show that $$EA=PAQ.$$
Since $E$ is invertible:
$$A=E^{-1}PAQ,$$
So by taking $E=P$ and $Q=I$, where $I$ is identity matrix, the statement is proven.
 $\square$

Comment: Your first line is incorrect. There is not necessarily an elementary matrix for which $EA = R$. However, there exists a sequence of elementary matrices $E_1,\dots,E_k$ for which 
$$
E_{k} \cdots E_2 E_1 A = R.
$$
You could take $E = E_{k} \cdots E_2E_1$ and proceed with the proof

Comment: Also, it is not true that $A = E^{-1}PAQ$ "is possible if and only if $E^{-1}P = I$ and $Q = I$".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Okay, it feels pedantic : there is a matrix $E$, which is row equivalent to a elementary matrix, therefore $E$ is invertible.

Comment: More simply: $E$ is a product of elementary matrices and is therefore invertible

Comment: @Omnomnomnom "Also, it is not true that..."
why?

Comment: You are making the assumption that if $M = PMQ$, then $P = I$ and $Q = I$.  However, this is false.  As an example, consider
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}.
$$
If you take $P = Q = M$ (or $P = I$ and $Q = M$), then $M = PMQ$, but it is not true that $P = I$ and $Q = I$.

Comment: When you're going through the proofs in the first chapter of a textbook, the pedantic distinctions are particularly important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is incorrect in its current form, as I point out in my comments.  Here is a correct version.

---

*Proof*
Since $R$ is obtained from $A$, there exists a sequence of elementary matrices $E_1,\dots,E_k$ for which 
$$
E_{k} \cdots E_2 E_1 A = R.
$$
Let $E = E_{k} \cdots E_2E_1$.  We see that 
$$
R = EA = EAI.
$$
Thus, the desired statement holds with $P = E$ and $Q = I_{n \times n}$. $\square$

Comment: Thank you very much for correct wording. I added edited proof at the end of OP as well.

Comment: @flowian Your new proof looks fine.  I would have added in  "we need to show that *there exist invertible matrices $P,Q$ for which....*" for clarity. I think the primary difference in our approaches is that you find it particularly intuitive to "plug in" $R = PAQ$.

Comment: Yes, I tried to work up the proof by assuming that $R=PAQ$  *is true*, and luckily, it worked.
I feel that your approach is more straightforward. I myself would not come up to multiply $R=EA$ by $I$ and then sort of deduce that $Q=I$ though.

Comment: @flowian I think you're stuck in the mindset that we're "solving for" $P$ and $Q$. When you're showing that a solution exists (rather than finding the unique solution or set of all possible solutions), you can approach the problem a lot more flexibly.

Comment: Was this your initial thought process though? Or you found out that $Q=I$, and then made the proof more compact?

Comment: @flowian My thought process was more along the lines of "starting from $A$, the goal is to reach $R$ using only multiplication by invertible matrices". Since we already reached $R$ after using $E$, we're done!

Comment: When thinking about showing that solution exists, it indeed takes big burden from mind, as compared to when solving for $P,Q$.